# Intersection of two sets with the property of not having isolated points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm working in $\mathbb{R}$ with this example: $G = (a,b)\cap F$, where $F$ is closed, has at least one point in common with $(a,b)$ and does not have isolated points. I must show that $G$ also does not have isolated points.

I know that every open ball around any $x\in G$ must contain points in both $(a,b)$ and $F$. But I'm struggling to show that, given $x\in G$ and any ball around $x$, there is a point in this ball belonging to both $(a,b)$ and $F$.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in G$. Then we have $x\in F$ and $x\in ]a,b[$ (which is my notation for $(a,b)$). Since $]a, b[$ is open, there exists a ball $B\subset ]a,b[$ that contains $x$. Since $F$ has no isolated points, we must have $x\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Hence, $x$ is not isolated in $G$.